# iPhone SDK 3.0 - wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been working on an iPhone application, and since I started building on SDK 3.0 I receive this error whenever the application attempts to communicate with my webserver. Everything seems to be running fine, but I can't find anything that explains the root cause of the message. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I've seen this as well. I haven't been able to find any pattern to when it occurs.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error when I did:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

The error was gone when I used the following instead:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

What probably happened was that the navigation "slide" effect was initiated while the alertview hiding animation was still going on. After I changed this the animation was also smoother.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a cause of memory constraints (which manifest themselves in various ways). It's also possible that it's the cause of threaded interaction behaviour between when the downloads finishes and the UI at the time. Some people have indicated that there are issues with displaying a UIAlertView and creating a UIWebView, when the latter is created before the former. If you have a quick download connection (which is likely to be the case in the simulator and a local web server) then you might find it's the fact that your download is finishing too quickly for the UI to be ready to display a notification that the download is complete.